# Constrained optimization of a cost function for a matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I encountered this problem trying to implement an image processing algorithm.

I'm trying to minimize a cost function for a matrix subject to some constraints. The cost function is as follows:

$$J(U)=\sum_{\mathbf{r}}\Bigl(U(\mathbf{r})-\sum_{\mathbf{s}\in N(\mathbf{r})}w_{\mathbf{rs}} U(\mathbf{s})\Bigr)^2$$

Where $w_{\mathbf{rs}}$ is a weighting function:

$$w_{\mathbf{rs}}\propto\left(1+{1\over \sigma_{\mathbf{r}}^2}(U(\mathbf{r})-\mu_{\mathbf{r}})(U(\mathbf{s})-\mu_\mathbf{r})\right)$$

Each point in the matrix has a value of $J(U)$ associated with it. In the above formulas, $\mathbf{r}$ represents a point and $\mathbf{s}$ represents a neighboring (3 x 3 square) point in the matrix. The cost function for each point is a function of the point and surrounding points. $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constants for each point that I've already computed.

$U(\mathbf{r})$ is the just the value of a parameter $U$ at that point.

Some points are constrained to fixed values of $U$. The objective is to find values of $U$ for every point that minimize the cost function.

The package I'm working with has SciPy, so I have access [to these](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) optimization algorithms if any of them would be helpful. I'm relatively new to this kind of math.

I think the problem can be converted into a sparse system of linear equations but I'm not sure how to do so.

Approximate solutions are fine.

Comment: I added parentheses to clarify what $w_{rs}$ is proportional to - if this isn't what you meant, feel free to revert edit.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee thanks, that's correct.

Comment: Are there any inequality-type constraints? It looks like the constraints are just that some of the points in $U$ must have specific values. In that case, this reduces to optimization of a multivariable function $J(x_1, x_2, ...)$ with the $x_i$ being any entries of $U$ that aren't fixed. This has no inequality constraint - which means we want to find the points where the gradient of your function is equal to the zero vector. If you have $n$ entries in the matrix $U$ whose values are variable, then you will have a system of $n$ equations after setting the gradient of $J$ equal to $0$.

Comment: [This video has a great visual explanation of using the gradient to minimize/maximize multivariable functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ux7EQ3ip2DU). Because there are no inequality constraints, it shouldn't be necessary to use any other methods such as Karush-Kuhn-Tucker or Lagrance multipliers. Anyway, if there are no inequality-type constraints then I'll flesh out the above comment into an answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that the set of points (for which the gradient of $J$ is equal to the zero vector) include local maxima and minima, and multidimensional equivalents of saddle points. More tests need to be done before you can be sure that a point is a global minimum.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, yes, fixed constraints only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like none of your constraints in this problem are inequalities. This means we can write $J$ as a function of all of the entries of the matrix $U$ whose values are variable (you mentioned that some entries of $U$ are fixed and some are variable).

Suppose there are $n$ entries of $U$ whose values are variable - call them $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$. Then, using the two equations from your question, you will be able to write out the cost function $J$, as a function of  $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$.

Once you have done this, you will want to find the set of candidate points (points with $n$ coordinates, in this case) for the global minimum of $J$. To do this, [you will want to set the **gradient** of $J$ equal to the zero vector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ux7EQ3ip2DU). The gradient of $J$ is itself a vector with $n$ entries, so setting the gradient of $J$ equal to the zero vector will result in a system of $n$ equations.

The solution set to this system of $n$ equations will be the candidate points for the global minimum of $J$. Some of these points may be local minima, local maxima, or [the equivalent of saddle points](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aAU4r_pUUU). We wish to eliminate those points so that only the global minimum remains. You will need to find the all of the second-order partial derivatives of $J$ to compute the [Hessian matrix of $J$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix).

You can then use the [method described in the last page of this document](http://faculty.csuci.edu/brian.sittinger/2nd_DerivTest.pdf) to determine which of your candidate points will be your final answer.

---

The most tedious part of solving this problem will probably actually be writing $J$ in terms of $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$. It will not be very difficult, but it will be time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on implementing this. The function will be working with > 500,000 variables since it's processing images.

Comment: @eliminate1337 Good luck! You will definitely want to look into algorithms for computing Hessian matrices. It would be awful to have a program individually compute $500000^2$ second-order partial derivatives of a $500000$-variable function.

Comment: @eliminate1337 Out of curiosity, what are you going to use your finished algorithm for? Could you just use existing image-processing code? People have probably already optimized those algorithms to a great extent

Comment: It's for colorizing an image. It's a relatively new and novel algorithm so there's not much code out there for it. The authors of the paper I'm referencing provided code, but it's a brute force solution. I'm hoping to write a better version that uses SciPy's already optimized minimization functions.

Comment: Very interesting - good luck :)